# Replace all NSNull objects in an NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary, json-framework, nsnull

I'm curious, I currently have an `NSDictionary` where some values are set to an `NSNull` object thanks to the help of json-framework.

The aim is to strip all `NSNull` values and replace it with an empty string.

I'm sure someone has done this somewhere? No doubt it is probably a four liner and is simple, I am just far too burnt out to figure this out on my own.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21922026/assign-nsnull-object-to-nsstring/21922246?noredirect=1#comment33222314_21922246

Comment: I made a category which does that. You can find it here https://github.com/bismasaeed00/NullReplacer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Really simple:

```
@interface NSDictionary (JRAdditions)
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings;
@end

@implementation NSDictionary (JRAdditions)

- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings {
   const NSMutableDictionary *replaced = [self mutableCopy];
   const id nul = [NSNull null];
   const NSString *blank = @"";

   for(NSString *key in self) {
      const id object = [self objectForKey:key];
      if(object == nul) {
         //pointer comparison is way faster than -isKindOfClass:
         //since [NSNull null] is a singleton, they'll all point to the same
         //location in memory.
         [replaced setObject:blank 
                      forKey:key];
      }
   }

   return [replaced copy];
}

@end
```

Usage:

```
NSDictionary *someDictThatHasNulls = ...;
NSDictionary *replacedDict = [someDictThatHasNulls dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings];
```

Comment: Or, since `NSNull` is a singleton, you can test value pointers directly: `if([self objectForKey:key]==[NSNull null])`.

Comment: *Yes*.. **But** what if dictionary contains **NSArray** of NULL's? Or other **NSDictionary** with NULL's values? Be carefully to use this! I highly recommend to use Stakenborg's modification of this method, described below!

Comment: Use Stakenborg's method below!

Comment: Where do we copy and paste this to? This gives me errors when I try it and paste to file I want it in below, sorry im new to iOS

Answer (score 44):

I've made a few changes to Jacob's original answer to extend it to handle dictionaries and arrays stored within the original dictionary.

```
#import "NSDictionary+NullReplacement.h"
#import "NSArray+NullReplacement.h"

@implementation NSDictionary (NullReplacement)

- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithBlanks {
    const NSMutableDictionary *replaced = [self mutableCopy];
    const id nul = [NSNull null];
    const NSString *blank = @"";
    
    for (NSString *key in self) {
        id object = [self objectForKey:key];
        if (object == nul) [replaced setObject:blank forKey:key];
        else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) [replaced setObject:[object dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithBlanks] forKey:key];
        else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) [replaced setObject:[object arrayByReplacingNullsWithBlanks] forKey:key];
    }
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[replaced copy]];
}

@end
```

And there's also an array category of course:

```
#import "NSArray+NullReplacement.h"
#import "NSDictionary+NullReplacement.h"

@implementation NSArray (NullReplacement)

- (NSArray *)arrayByReplacingNullsWithBlanks  {
    NSMutableArray *replaced = [self mutableCopy];
    const id nul = [NSNull null];
    const NSString *blank = @"";
    for (int idx = 0; idx < [replaced count]; idx++) {
        id object = [replaced objectAtIndex:idx];
        if (object == nul) [replaced replaceObjectAtIndex:idx withObject:blank];
        else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) [replaced replaceObjectAtIndex:idx withObject:[object dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithBlanks]];
        else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) [replaced replaceObjectAtIndex:idx withObject:[object arrayByReplacingNullsWithBlanks]];
    }
    return [replaced copy];
}

@end
```

With this, you can take any array or dictionary and recursively wipe out all the [NSNull null] instances.

P.S. For completion's sake, here are the header files:

```
@interface NSDictionary (NullReplacement)

- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithBlanks;

@end
```

And the array header:

```
@interface NSArray (NullReplacement)

- (NSArray *)arrayByReplacingNullsWithBlanks;

@end
```

Comment: I made a category which does that. You can find it here https://github.com/bismasaeed00/NullReplacer

Answer (score 6):

Rolling through the dictionary hunting for NSNull is one way to tackle the problem, but I took a slightly lazier approach. Instead of nil you could assign an empty string, but the principle is the same.

### CPJSONDictionary.h

```
@interface NSDictionary (CPJSONDictionary)
- (id)jsonObjectForKey:(id)aKey;
@end
```

### CPJSONDictionary.m

```
@implementation NSDictionary (CPJSONDictionary)

- (id)jsonObjectForKey:(id)aKey {
    id object = [self objectForKey:aKey];
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        object = nil;
    }

    return object;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4):

I have tested Stakenborg solution. It works well, but it has following problem. If some object is expected to be number, for instance, converting it to `NSNull` can be a source of error.
I have create a new method to directly remove the `NSNull` entries. This way you only have to check that correspondant key exists.

Add in `NSDictionary+NullReplacement`

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryByRemovingNulls{
    const NSMutableDictionary *replaced = [self mutableCopy];
    const id nul = [NSNull null];
    
    for (NSString *key in self) {
        id object = [self objectForKey:key];
        if (object == nul) [replaced removeObjectForKey:key];
        
        else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) [replaced setObject:[object dictionaryByRemovingNulls] forKey:key];
        else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) [replaced setObject:[object arrayByRemovingNulls] forKey:key];
    }
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[replaced copy]];
}
```

And in `NSArray+NullReplacement`

```
- (NSArray *)arrayByRemovingNulls {
    NSMutableArray *replaced = [self mutableCopy];
    const id nul = [NSNull null];

    for (int idx = [replaced count]-1; idx >=0; idx--) {
        id object = [replaced objectAtIndex:idx];
        if (object == nul) [replaced removeObjectAtIndex:idx];
        else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) [replaced replaceObjectAtIndex:idx withObject:[object dictionaryByRemovingNulls]];
        else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) [replaced replaceObjectAtIndex:idx withObject:[object arrayByRemovingNulls]];
    }
    return [replaced copy];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

another variation:

```
NSDictionary * NewDictionaryReplacingNSNullWithEmptyNSString(NSDictionary * dict) {
    NSMutableDictionary * const m = [dict mutableCopy];    
    NSString * const empty = @"";
    id const nul = [NSNull null];
    NSArray * const keys = [m allKeys];
    for (NSUInteger idx = 0, count = [keys count]; idx < count; ++idx) {
        id const key = [keys objectAtIndex:idx];
        id const obj = [m objectForKey:key];
        if (nul == obj) {
            [m setObject:empty forKey:key]; 
        }
    }

    NSDictionary * result = [m copy];
    [m release];
    return result;
}
```

The result is the same as, and it *appears* pretty much identical to Jacob's, but the speed and memory requirements are one half to one third (ARC or MRC) in the tests I made. Of course, you could also use it as a category method as well.

Comment: Simple code, but it just replaces nulls in the root branch of an NSDictionary, so failed to remove the NULLs from my NSDictionary value, from a JSON service.  Stakenborg's code below worked a treat though.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)cleanNullInJsonDic:(NSDictionary *)dic
{
    if (!dic || (id)dic == [NSNull null])
    {
        return dic;
    }
    NSMutableDictionary *mulDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (NSString *key in [dic allKeys])
    {
        NSObject *obj = dic[key];
        if (!obj || obj == [NSNull null])
        {
//            [mulDic setObject:[@"" JSONValue] forKey:key];
        }else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
            [mulDic setObject:[self cleanNullInJsonDic:(NSDictionary *)obj] forKey:key];
        }else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        {
            NSArray *array = [BasicObject cleanNullInJsonArray:(NSArray *)obj];
            [mulDic setObject:array forKey:key];
        }else
        {
            [mulDic setObject:obj forKey:key];
        }
    }
    return mulDic;
}


+ (NSArray *)cleanNullInJsonArray:(NSArray *)array
{
    if (!array || (id)array == [NSNull null])
    {
        return array;
    }
    NSMutableArray *mulArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSObject *obj in array)
    {
        if (!obj || obj == [NSNull null])
        {
//            [mulArray addObject:[@"" JSONValue]];
        }else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
            NSDictionary *dic = [self cleanNullInJsonDic:(NSDictionary *)obj];
            [mulArray addObject:dic];
        }else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        {
            NSArray *a = [BasicObject cleanNullInJsonArray:(NSArray *)obj];
            [mulArray addObject:a];
        }else
        {
            [mulArray addObject:obj];
        }
    }
    return mulArray;
}
```

Comment: This works like a charm in my case where the dictionary contains dictionary and array objects. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

```
-(NSDictionary*)stripNulls:(NSDictionary*)dict{

    NSMutableDictionary *returnDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    NSArray *allKeys = [dict allKeys];
    NSArray *allValues = [dict allValues];

    for (int i=0; i<[allValues count]; i++) {
        if([allValues objectAtIndex:i] == (NSString*)[NSNull null]){
            [returnDict setValue:@"" forKey:[allKeys objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
    else
        [returnDict setValue:[allValues objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[allKeys objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

return returnDict;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A category on nsnull that returns nil seems to also sense, at least to me. There are a few out there. One makes all calls return nil which seems to make sense. Sorry no link. I guess if you need to later use nspropertylistserialization the category might not work for you.