# Replace occurrences of NSNull in nested NSDictionary

Tags: ios, plist, nsdictionary, replace, nsnull

This question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075147/replace-all-nsnull-objects-in-an-nsdictionary), however this method only works on the root level of the dictionary.

I'm looking to replace any occurrence of `NSNull` values with an empty string, so that I can save the full dictionary to a plist file (if i add it with the NSNull's the file won't write).

My dictionary, however, has nested dictionaries inside it. Like this:

```
"dictKeyName" = {
    innerStrKeyName = "This is a string in a dictionary";
    innerNullKeyName = "<null>";
    innerDictKeyName = {
        "innerDictStrKeyName" = "This is a string in a Dictionary in another Dictionary";
        "innerDictNullKeyName" = "<null>";
    };
};
```

If I use:

```
@interface NSDictionary (JRAdditions)
- (NSDictionary *) dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings;
@end

@implementation NSDictionary (JRAdditions)

- (NSDictionary *) dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings {

    const NSMutableDictionary *replaced = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:self];
    const id nul = [NSNull null];
    const NSString *blank = @"";

    for(NSString *key in replaced) {
        const id object = [self objectForKey:key];
        if(object == nul) {
            [replaced setObject:blank forKey:key];
        }
    }
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:replaced];
}

@end
```

I get something like this:

```
"dictKeyName" = {
    innerStrKeyName = "This is a string in a dictionary";
    innerNullKeyName = ""; <-- this value has changed
    innerDictKeyName = {
        "innerDictStrKeyName" = "This is a string in a Dictionary in another Dictionary";
        "innerDictNullKeyName" = "<null>"; <-- this value hasn't changed
    };
};
```

Is there a way of finding every `NSNull` value from all dictionaries including nested dictionaries...?

**EDIT:**
The data is being drawn from a JSON feed, so the data I receive is dynamic (and I don't want to have to update the app everytime the feed changes).

Comment: Also you really should post actual code

"<null>" <-- thats neither an NSString or a null

Comment: That is the actual response i'm getting. I'm parsing a JSON Feed and the dictionary is the response. When I log it out, it comes out as "<null>" and is recognised in the find and replace for loop as [NSNull null].

Comment: The code you have is to manipulate NSDictionary so when you parse your JSON call the method to remove the NSNulls

Comment: Do you have any examples of how to do this?

Comment: Are you still having an issue with this? Did any of the answers resolve the problem?

Comment: Nope, still the same issues...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A small modification to the method can make it recursive:

```
@interface NSDictionary (JRAdditions)
- (NSDictionary *) dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings;
@end

@implementation NSDictionary (JRAdditions)

- (NSDictionary *) dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings {
    const NSMutableDictionary *replaced = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: self];
    const id nul = [NSNull null];
    const NSString *blank = @"";

    for (NSString *key in self) {
        const id object = [self objectForKey: key];
        if (object == nul) {
            [replaced setObject: blank forKey: key];
        }
        else if ([object isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary class]]) {
            [replaced setObject: [(NSDictionary *) object dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings] forKey: key];
        }
    }
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: replaced];
}
```

Note that the fast-enumeration is now on **`self`** instead of **`replaced`**

With the code above, this example:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dic1 setObject: @"string 1" forKey: @"key1.1"];
[dic1 setObject: [NSNull null] forKey: @"key1.2"];

NSMutableDictionary *dic2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dic2 setObject: @"string 2" forKey: @"key2.1"];
[dic2 setObject: [NSNull null] forKey: @"key2.2"];

[dic1 setObject: dic2 forKey: @"key1.3"];

NSLog(@"%@", dic1);
NSLog(@"%@", [dic1 dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings]);
```

renders this result:

```
2012-09-01 08:30:16.210 Test[57731:c07] {
    "key1.1" = "string 1";
    "key1.2" = "<null>";
    "key1.3" =     {
        "key2.1" = "string 2";
        "key2.2" = "<null>";
    };
}
2012-09-01 08:30:16.212 Test[57731:c07] {
    "key1.1" = "string 1";
    "key1.2" = "";
    "key1.3" =     {
        "key2.1" = "string 2";
        "key2.2" = "";
    };
```

Comment: Really? I've added a usage-example with its output.

Comment: The last line is superfluous; it would suffice to `return replaced;` instead.

Comment: What if the object is NSArray?

Comment: How to handle in nested json strin, see in this post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48009583/ios-objective-c-remove-null-from-json-string

Comment: I'd use for (NSString *key in [self allKeys]) even if the current implementation works - because it's both less readable, and you need to dig down a lot to know that fast-enumeration over NSDictionary enumerates keys. (could be values, or pairs, or whatever.

Comment: Also - there are faster enumeration mechanisms for NSDictionary, that are concurrent, and also employ background queues, like
    [replaced enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString*  _Nonnull key, NSString*  _Nonnull value, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) { if (value == [NSNull null]) [self setValue:@"N/A" forKey:key]; }];

Answer (score 10):

It works for me, I used nested looping to replace all NULL with nil in the entire dictionary including NSArray.

```
- (NSDictionary *) dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithNil:(NSDictionary*)sourceDictionary {

    NSMutableDictionary *replaced = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:sourceDictionary];
    const id nul = [NSNull null];

    for(NSString *key in replaced) {
        const id object = [sourceDictionary objectForKey:key];
        if(object == nul) {
            [replaced setValue:nil forKey:key];
        }
    }
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:replaced];
}

-(NSDictionary *) nestedDictionaryByReplacingNullsWithNil:(NSDictionary*)sourceDictionary
{
    NSMutableDictionary *replaced = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:sourceDictionary];
    const id nul = [NSNull null];
    const NSString *blank = @"";
    [sourceDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {
        object = [sourceDictionary objectForKey:key];
        if([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
            NSDictionary *innerDict = object;
            [replaced setObject:[self nestedDictionaryByReplacingNullsWithNil:innerDict] forKey:key];

        }
        else if([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
            NSMutableArray *nullFreeRecords = [NSMutableArray array];
            for (id record in object) {

                if([record isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
                {
                    NSDictionary *nullFreeRecord = [self nestedDictionaryByReplacingNullsWithNil:record];
                    [nullFreeRecords addObject:nullFreeRecord];
                }
            }
            [replaced setObject:nullFreeRecords forKey:key];
        }
        else
        {
            if(object == nul) {
                [replaced setObject:blank forKey:key];
            }
        }
    }];

    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:replaced];  
}
```

Comment: this implementation is much useful than the accepted one cause it takes arrays into account

Comment: This implementation won't take into account arrays, which contain non-dictionary data (e.g. strings or arrays). It will return an empty array

Comment: Excuse me... but [someMutableDictionary setValue:nil forKey @"someKey"] does NOT introduce a nil into the dictionary- that would crash immediately. Instead it REMOVES the key/value pair altogether. I'm not sure this is good as answer to the OP needs

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone needs this for swift 1.2, here's the snippet:

```
class func removeNullsFromDictionary(origin:[String:AnyObject]) -> [String:AnyObject] {
    var destination:[String:AnyObject] = [:]
    for key in origin.keys {
        if origin[key] != nil && !(origin[key] is NSNull){
            if origin[key] is [String:AnyObject] {
                destination[key] = self.removeNullsFromDictionary(origin[key] as! [String:AnyObject])
            } else if origin[key] is [AnyObject] {
                let orgArray = origin[key] as! [AnyObject]
                var destArray: [AnyObject] = []
                for item in orgArray {
                    if item is [String:AnyObject] {
                        destArray.append(self.removeNullsFromDictionary(item as! [String:AnyObject]))
                    } else {
                        destArray.append(item)
                    }
                }
                destination[key] = destArray
            } else {
                destination[key] = origin[key]
            }
        } else {
            destination[key] = ""
        }
    }
    return destination
}
```

Comment: works, but you forgot the **destination[key] = destArray** at end of cycle

Comment: @Danilo, Thanks for the comment, i edited the snippet

Answer (score 2):

Following method works perfectly for any number of nested arrray of dictionary:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings:(NSDictionary *)jobList
{
    NSMutableDictionary *replaced = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:jobList];
    const id nul = [NSNull null];
    const NSString *blank = @"";

    for (NSString *key in [replaced allKeys])
    {
        id object = [replaced objectForKey:key];
        if (object == nul)
        {
            [replaced setObject:blank
                         forKey:key];
        }
        else
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
            [replaced setObject:[self replaceNullInNested:object]
                         forKey:key];
        }
        else
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        {
            NSMutableArray *dc = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for (NSDictionary *tempDict in object)
            {
                [dc addObject:[self dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings:tempDict]];
            }
            [replaced setObject:dc
                         forKey:key];
        }
    }
    return replaced;
}

- (NSMutableDictionary *)replaceNullInNested:(NSDictionary *)targetDict
{
    // make it to be NSMutableDictionary in case that it is nsdictionary
    NSMutableDictionary *m = [targetDict mutableCopy];
    NSMutableDictionary *replaced = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:m];
    const id nul = [NSNull null];
    const NSString *blank = @"";

    for (NSString *key in [replaced allKeys])
    {
        const id object = [replaced objectForKey:key];
        if (object == nul)
        {
            [replaced setObject:blank
                         forKey:key];
        }
        else
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        {
//            NSLog(@"found null inside and key is %@", key);
            // make it to be able to set value by create a new one
            NSMutableArray *a = [object mutableCopy];
            for (int i = 0; i < [a count]; i++)
            {
                for (NSString *subKey in [[a objectAtIndex:i] allKeys])
                {
                    if ([[object objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:subKey] == nul)
                    {
                        [[object objectAtIndex:i] setValue:blank
                                                    forKey:subKey];
                    }
                }
            }
            // replace the updated one with old one
            [replaced setObject:a
                         forKey:key];
        }
    }
    return replaced;
}
```

I used above modified method as per my required functionality:

// Call Method

```
NSMutableDictionary *sortedDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (NSString *key in jobList){
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *tempDict in [jobList objectForKey:key])
    {
        [tempArray addObject:[self dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings:tempDict]];
    }
    [sortedDict setObject:tempArray forKey:key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
@interface NSDictionary (JRAdditions)
    - (NSDictionary *) dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings;
@end
```

Monkey patches NSDictionary - which means you can call dictionaryByReplacing...
On not just the root but any nested dictionaries as you please.

I dont really agree with this from a design standpoint but it does solve your problem.

Comment: I know this, but I the data is dynamic, so I don't want to have to re-release the code every time the dictionary is updated.

Comment: Check if object is a dictionary and replace with with result of calling method.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@interface NSDictionary (JRAdditions)
 - (NSDictionary *) dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings;
 -(NSDictionary *) nestedDictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings;
@end

@implementation NSDictionary (JRAdditions)

- (NSDictionary *) dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings {

const NSMutableDictionary *replaced = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:self];
const id nul = [NSNull null];
const NSString *blank = @"";

for(NSString *key in replaced) {
    const id object = [self objectForKey:key];
    if(object == nul) {
        [replaced setObject:blank forKey:key];
    }
}
return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:replaced];
}

-(NSDictionary *) nestedDictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings
{  
  const NSMutableDictionary *replaced = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:self];
  const id nul = [NSNull null];
  const NSString *blank = @"";
  for(id *item in replaced) {
    const id object = [self objectForKey:key];
    if([object isKindofClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
       NSDictionary *innerDict = object;
       [replaced setObject:[innerDict dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings] forKey:key];

    }
    else
    {
     if(object == nul) {
        [replaced setObject:blank forKey:key];
     }
    }
 }
 return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:replaced];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works with arrays and dictionaries, and also for nested arrays and dictionaries etc (recursively).

```
- (NSDictionary *)writableDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dictionary];

    for (id key in mutableDictionary.allKeys)
    {
        id value = mutableDictionary[key];
        mutableDictionary[key] = [self writableValue:value];
    }

    return mutableDictionary;
}

- (NSArray *)writableArray:(NSArray *)array
{
    NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];

    for (int i = 0; i < mutableArray.count; ++i)
    {
        id value = mutableArray[i];
        mutableArray[i] = [self writableValue:value];
    }

    return mutableArray;
}

- (id)writableValue:(id)value
{
    if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    {
        value = @"";
    }
    else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        value = [self writableDictionary:value];
    }
    else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        value = [self writableArray:value];
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned answers does not cater the situation if you have array in your dictionary. Check this out

```
+(NSMutableDictionary*)getValuesWithOutNull:(NSDictionary          
     *)yourDictionary{
       NSMutableDictionary *replaced = [NSMutableDictionary 
     dictionaryWithDictionary: yourDictionary];
      id nul = [NSNull null];
      NSString *blank = @"";

for (NSString *key in yourDictionary) {
    const id object = [yourDictionary objectForKey: key];
    if (object == nul) {
        [replaced setObject: blank forKey: key];
    }
    else if ([object isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary class]]) {
        [replaced setObject:[self getValuesWithOutNull:object] 
forKey:key];
    }
    else if([object isKindOfClass: [NSArray class]])
    {
        NSMutableArray *array  = [NSMutableArray 
arrayWithArray:object];
        for(int i = 0 ;i < array.count;i++)
        {
            NSDictionary *dict = [array objectAtIndex:i];
            [array replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[self 
  getValuesWithOutNull:dict]];
        }
        [replaced setObject:array forKey:key];
    }
 }
  return  replaced;

}
```