# Scrolling issue Table View with JSON data

Tags: ios, json, parsing, uitableview

I'm parsing some data from a JSON-file located on my server to my Table View.
When I launch the app the app successfully downloads the data to my table view, but when I begin to scroll, the app crashes.

Here's my code:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "YoutubePost.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize tableView = _tableView, activityIndicatorView = _activityIndicatorView, movies = _movies;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Videos", @"Videos");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newtab1"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Setting Up Activity Indicator View
    self.activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    self.activityIndicatorView.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    self.activityIndicatorView.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:self.activityIndicatorView];
    [self.activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Initializing Data Source
    self.movies = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://my-website.com/link-to-json.php?name=Name&orderby=published"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        self.movies = JSON;
        [self.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    }];

    [operation start];
}

// Table View Data Source Methods
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.movies && self.movies.count) {
        return self.movies.count;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 378;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"YoutubePost";

    YoutubePost *cell = (YoutubePost *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YoutubePost" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }

    NSDictionary *movie = [self.movies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.title.text = [movie objectForKey:@"title"];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[movie objectForKey:@"link"]];

    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];    
    NSString * storyLink = [[_movies objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey:@"link"];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:storyLink]];
    NSString *formattedJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[self.tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"tweet:\n%@", formattedJSON);
}

@end
```

What is wrong? I see that the data successfully downloads to my custom Table View Cell, but every time I try to scroll down the app crashes. Please help me fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: What does the console show when then app crashes?

Comment: Can you post your crash log? why it crashes?

Comment: @NickGalasso The crash log is totally empty.

Comment: Did you set the custom cell **Identifier** in the nib file of your YoutubePost cell to be "YoutubePost"?

Comment: @Refael.S Yep. I don't think that's the problem, because when I launch the app everything parses correctly and my custom cell works fine. But when I begin to scroll the app freezes.

Comment: Why are you extracting a URL and not using it?
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[movie objectForKey:@"link"]];

Comment: Try setting breakpoints to find what line of code is making your app crash

Comment: @Refael.S I forgot to delete that. I used it before when I parsed a link to an image. But that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You should check the class of JSON to make sure it's an array.

Comment: Do you have a exception breakpoint enabled?  Where is the error originating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct this:

```
    // Initializing Data Source
    //self.movies = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://my-website.com/link-to-json.php?name=Name&orderby=published"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        self.movies = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:JSON];
        [self.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    }];

    [operation start];
```

And in your YouTubePost Nib add Identifier "YouTubePost":

[image]

And also in your YouTubePost Nib select your title UILabel and in the inspector change from:
[image: Line Breaks]

To:

[image: Line Breaks]

**Or Change:**

[image: Lines 2]

To:

[image: Lines 1]

This will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Change the lines below:

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YoutubePost" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

}
```

Like this:

```
if (cell == nil)
{
     UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"YoutubePost" bundle:nil];

    [tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"YoutubePost"];

    tableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YoutubePost"];
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide us more detailed information? We need to know what is stored in your array. In addition to this what is YouToubePost? Is it subclassed from UITableViewCell and is there any nib with the same name?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not doing any checking for `[NSNull null]` in your JSON. It is possible that the following code will give you `[NSNull null]` instead of an `NSDictionary`:

```
NSDictionary *movie = [self.movies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

You should filter these out before calling `reloadData`

Similarly, this line could also potentially return `[NSNull null]`:

```
cell.title.text = [movie objectForKey:@"title"];
```

You need to be prepared to handle that case. This may help you:
 [Replace all NSNull objects in an NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075147/replace-all-nsnull-objects-in-an-nsdictionary)