# Assign NSNull Object to NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsnull

I'm writing an iOS App where i need to get data from a SQL-Database over mobile Services from Azure.

After downloading the data I get a `NSDictionary` with all attributes from the SQL-Table. If an attribute is empty, the value is `NSNull`.

Is there a way to pass `NSNull` to `NSString` without an IF-Statement (I don't want to have 20 if statements..)?

Comment: Damn it! But thank you for your quick answer!

Comment: Write a simple help method or function that returns what you want based on passing in either a string or `NSNull`. Then you don't need lots of `if` statements. Just a simple method or function call.

Comment: "Pass NSNull to NSString" makes no sense.  You can certainly assign an NSNull to a pointer that's typed `NSString*`, though, without any real difficulty.  Maybe you need to give us an example of your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote a category just for dealing with this issue. I used it with Core Data but it should help you, too.

```
@interface NSDictionary (Extensions)

- (id)NSNullToNilForKey:(NSString *)key;

@end

@implementation NSDictionary (Extensions)

- (id)NSNullToNilForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    id value = [self valueForKey:key];

    return value != [NSNull null] ? value : nil;
}

@end
```

Sample use:

```
NSString *value = [dictionary NSNullToNilForKey:@"key"];
```

Comment: You're welcome. :) I use this category extensively when converting JSON structures to Core Data entities, since the JSON deserializer I use deserializes null values to `[NSNull null]`.

Comment: exactly the thing i want to use it!

Comment: Could you list steps on how to implement this?

Comment: @John Sorry, I haven't done iOS programming in years, but it should be as simple as just creating a new class file and header file, no?

Answer (score 2):

You can't just assign it, but you can filter out all of the `NSNull` instances using something like this:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = // data from server
NSDictionary *filteredDictionary = [dictionary mutableCopy];

NSSet *keysToRemove = [orig keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^BOOL(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    if (obj == [NSNull null]) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}];
[filteredDictionary removeObjectsForKeys:[keysToRemove allObjects]];
```

Now you have the same dictionary except that every key with an `NSNull` has been removed.