# How to remove White spaces in JSON String in Objective-c

Tags: ios

I am converting my json string to `NSMutableDictionary` by using below code,it's working fine,but if there is any unwanted white spaces are there then dictionary become null,i tested it with JSON lint, JSON parser, if i remove manually that white space that JSON string become valid, there is any method to remove that white spaces in JSON String.

```
NSMutableDictionary  *responseDictionary;
         NSData * data = (NSData *)responseObject;
         NSString *jsonString =  [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                              options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                error:nil];
         NSLog(@"the value in the dic is%@",responseDictionary);
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Sounds like it needs to be fixed in the software producing the JSON.

Comment: please see this link :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075147/replace-all-nsnull-objects-in-an-nsdictionary

Comment: possible duplicate of [Collapse sequences of white space into a single character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758212/collapse-sequences-of-white-space-into-a-single-character)

Comment: If NSJSONSerialization doesn't parse it, then it isn't JSON. Complain to whoever produces the data. Trying to modify the data to make it parse is highly dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if you're certain that you need to do it yourself, here is a way to do it:

```
NSString *theString = @"    Hello      this  is a   long       string!   ";

NSCharacterSet *whitespaces = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
NSPredicate *noEmptyStrings = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != ''"];

NSArray *parts = [theString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:whitespaces];
NSArray *filteredArray = [parts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:noEmptyStrings];
theString = [filteredArray componentsJoinedByString:@""]; // using empty string to concatenate the strings
```

P.S. This is a slightly modified version of this answer (the author deserves an upvote IMHO): https://stackoverflow.com/a/1427224/2799410

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *newString= [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                                                           withString:@""];
```

Now the `newString` will not have any white spaces.

Comment: The PO wanted to remove not only single spaces, but all occurrences of characters of the whitespace family (e.g. newline characters, spaces, tabs, etc.).

Comment: So you can try this:<br>NSString *string = @"Hello, World!";
NSCharacterSet *separator = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
NSArray *stringComponents = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separator];

Comment: That's exactly what I proposed right here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32861064/2799410

Comment: i tried with this ,but the result is same as previous.