# I'm getting from the database dictionary in which there is one or more objects NSNull

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, nsdictionary, nsnull

I'm getting from the database dictionary in which there is one or more objects `NSNull`. In the future, I can not in any way to work with him as the app crash. I tried many ways to remove from the dictionary `NSNull` objects, method `removeObjectForKey` but any attempt to do this I get an error that is an array of reason:

```
- [__ NSArrayM removeObjectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to an instance
```

And I can not remove these objects by method the array `removeObjectAtIndex` as this dictionary. I only thought of how to do this is to remove these objects by type. Is it possible to do so, remove the object from the dictionary that match `NSNull` type? Or maybe there is another solution to this problem?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Post the contents of your source 'dictionary', or 'array', or whatever it might be.

Comment: `NSArrayM` is clearly a mutable array (`NSMutableArray`), not a dictionary. arrays are index based, dictionaries are key based.

Answer (score 0):

This loop (adapted from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075147/replace-all-nsnull-objects-in-an-nsdictionary)) should help you substitute the NSnull entries with a string of your choice (forgive typos, I am not in front of my computer).

```
for(NSString *key in yourDictionary) {
  id dictionaryEntry= [yourDictionary objectForKey:key];
  if(!dictionaryEntry) {
     [newDictionary setObject:@"string" forKey:key];
  } else {
     [newDictionary setObject:[yourDictionary objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> And I can not remove these objects by method the array "removeObjectAtIndex" as this dictionary.

Unfortunately your error:

> [__ NSArrayM removeObjectForKey:]: unrecognized selector

Does not agree with you.  You have an array.  And the reason you cannot use `removeObjectAtIndex` is because it is immutable.

Comment: the problem is that I keep in the database objects in the dictionary and I returned dictionary. but when there gets nsnull then returns an array

Comment: Then that sounds like a different problem.  The solution to the problem above is that you're trying to call dictionary methods on an array.

Answer (score 0):

You are removing a key from an array

> Note down that you cannot remove a key from an array. Than this error is obvious.

Also for **removeObjectAtIndex**

> Make sure your array should be mutable. Then you can use removeObjectAtIndex.

Hope it works for you.